# QMAKE_POST_LINK in windows 10 issue

Tags: qt, qmake

> I have an Qt project wherein I build a lib and then use it in my main
>   project. For that purpose in the library's .pro file I need to copy the
>   generated libs to a certain folder. And for that purpose I am using
>   *QMAKE_POST_LINK*. The ones I have doesn't seem to work.

```
QML_INSTALL_PATH = C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\qml\Plot
QMAKE_DIR_SEP = "\\"

WDIR = $$replace(PWD, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy /y ..\Plot\*.*  $$QML_INSTALL_PATH &
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy /y $$WDIR\*.qml $$QML_INSTALL_PATH
```

Comment: it works but only if I rebuild the project everytime. Is there any setting to change that?

Answer (score 3):

> it works but only if I rebuild the project everytime

Since the library has been already linked, there's no need to copy it again. It only will get copied when it gets linked. That's the meaning of `QMAKE_POST_LINK`. It literally is "do this after you link", so when you don't link, it doesn't get done.

If you're removing the copy and want it auto-regenerated, you need to add a custom target.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $$QMAKE_COPY, and $$quote() around the arguments. I.e.

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$QMAKE_COPY $$quote(../Plot/*.*) $$quote($$QML_INSTALL_PATH) & $$QMAKE_COPY $$quote($$WDIR/*.qml) $$quote($$QML_INSTALL_PATH)
```

Comment: the one that I have used and yours works but only if I rebuild the project. It doesn't work simply when I build the project.